# How to use IndexedDB from two places

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

For example:
I have N tabs opened. From each of the tab I get a name from `<input>` that will be used as a store value in db. So, I'm supposed to have N stores. Each of the tabs has a button to connect into IDB and start saving objects into their own stores.
As far as I know from the manuals I can create new stores only by invoking `onupgradeneeded`. If my first tab will be using IDB and I will try with the 2nd tab to change IDB version to invoke `onupgradeneeded` will that work?
Is this possible to implement with IDB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onupgradeneeded` only runs when the version changes, so you'd have to be incrementing the version each time you add an object store. I don't think you really want to do it that way, because changing the version in one tab will require closing the databases in the other and then re-opening them at the higher version, because you can only have the latest version open at one time. Basically, it would become kind of messy and confusing.

Can you instead put everything in one object store? Maybe use the name from the `<input>` as the key, or put it in a property you index on? It's hard for me to say more without more detail about what you're actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: You could also make each value from <input> be its own DB with just one objectstore.

Comment: Well, I thought that I could use IDB the same as any SQL db where I am able to create tables in any moment and manipulate them from different places. Tbh this IDB behavior seems strange for me. Ofc I can create 10 dbs instead of 10 tables in 1 db but isn't it stupid?

Comment: The reason IDB works this way is to make it handling schema easy and explicit. Otherwise it'd be easy to wind up with some hacky ad hoc code to handle the fact that your users might have databases with different schemas. Instead, it forces all user DBs to upgrade to the latest version so your code can rely on that.

Comment: To expand on the "one object store" suggestion, a common approach would be to partition via a more complex key, e.g. using the `<input>` data as the first element in a two-entry array:

`store.put(value, [input_value, record_key])`